# string to if else statment

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I must use those strings to do the condition.
Because of the $op is string, so it cannot run the condition correctly. Please help.

```
<?php 
  //$op = $condition[$i]. " " .$operant[$i]. " " .$participant_index;
    $op = "1 == 5";
    if($type[$i]=="person" && $op){
      echo "ok";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: "I must use those strings to do the condition" --- any particular reason why?

Comment: There are functions to *evaluate* arbitrary strings as expressions, but it's highly recommended against, especially if you get the string from user input. What if the user [inputs something malicious](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: @zerkms: a more interesting question imho is: how does one "do" a "condition"?

Comment: I think that it is better to `$op` be boolean, not a string data type, like: `$op = 1 == 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    //$op = $condition[$i]. " " .$operant[$i]. " " .$participant_index;
    $op = "1 == 5";
    if($type[$i]=="person" && eval("return $op;"))
    {
       echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *evaluate* that string as code, PHP won't do that implicitly for you.
[`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) can do that, but since `eval` will freely execute any and all code you give it using full PHP permissions, **this is a giant security risk**, depending on where those strings come from.

The better solution is to use a limited expression engine which parses and evaluates the string, being able to only handle a few select expressions. You could write something like this yourself, but the difficulty of that greatly depends on what expressions you may possibly allow. The Symfony framework offers a decent [`ExpressionLanguage` component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html) which can already do just that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the value of `$op` isn't evil,  then use `eval`:

```
if ($type[$i]=="person" && eval("return ".$op){
    echo "ok";
}
```

Be carefull with this, as it will parse the content of `$op` as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The easy (but potentially harmful) way:

```
$op = "1 == 5";

if (eval("return " . $op . ";")) {
    // do your thing.
}
```

see http://php.net/eval